# Unsure whether to use bootstrap or not

Tags: inference, bootstrap

I've only recently came across the bootstrap procedure and I'm not entirely well versed in statistics so apologies if I'm completely wrong here. I'm looking at the average temperatures across a month generated by a climate model. I have an ensemble of 25 simulations, so I have temperature information for each day over 25 runs. My procedure so far was to take the mean June temperature for each simulation so I have 25 in total, then perform resampling 1000 times to get the sampling distribution of the mean. I did this because I thought 25 data points was quite low to reliably draw conclusions, but I've realised that I could just get the mean over all the temperature data from all the simulations, so 25*30 data points total. Which approach is more appropriate here?

Comment: Your procedure description is unclear, so it is hard to comment. However bootstrap *does nothing* about the reliability of the estimate or sample size. Bootstrap is used for estimating uncertainty of the estimator (mean in your case), it doesn't do anything to make the estimate more precise.

Comment: @Tim I suppose what I'm asking is: I have 25 datasets which contain 30 data points each, and I want to find the mean for the entire collection of data. Should I simply take the mean over the 25*30 data points, or take the mean of each data set individually, then resample to find the sampling distribution of the mean?

Comment: Why would you like to resample it?

Comment: @Tim from what I've read 25 data points (as I would have by the second method) is quite low and bootstrap is good for doing statistics when the amount of samples is low, I suspect I'm very wrong though

Comment: Bootstrap does not do anything about you having 25 data points. It does not grow your data anyhow.

Comment: @Tim so the second procedure I described doesn't make much sense? I think I've misunderstood the point of bootstrap so best not to use it I think